# If I have a rectangular loop moving through a magnetic field, which way will it go?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

If I have a rectangular loop moving through a magnetic field, which way will it go?

A uniform magnetic field (say it's pointing into the page)
A square/rectangular loop of wire moving into the field from left to right with constant speed.

The induced current should be counterclockwise right?

Comment: Why it should be counterclockwise? Show your reasoning.

Comment: Field going in -> try to oppose -> field going out -> ccw

Answer (score 1):

Use "Fleming's right hand rule" for generators and see what you'll get:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There will be no current induced. The magnetic flux contained within the loop is the same amount at all times, so there will be no change in magnetic flux. The speed of the loop is constant, so there will be no change of rate. As a current induced is proportional to the rate of change in magnetic flux (Faraday's law), there will be no induced current.

Comment: what if the loop is moving with a velcoity V, then there will be change in flux... so, will work be done in moving the loop?